# Side by side configuration

Tags: windows-8.1, runtime-error

I have got this error on my Windows 8.1 for every application:

> Error: The application has failed to start because the side by side
>   configuration is incorrect please see the application event log or use
>   the command line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail

I have see on some forum that I should reinstall c++ runtime packages, but also the installers give this error message. I can not run anything.

Comment: Your Windows installation is corrupt.  The first set would be to try `sfc /scannow` after that use `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` have you done what this error said to do?  I don't see the results of sxstrace.exe

Comment: follow this: http://pastebin.com/ZbfMC41R If you're unsure, upload the SxSTrace.txt